# message when using find command parmeter -cmin or -mmin " FSUM6372 Unknown option "-cmin" "

Tags: unix, find, mainframe

while trying to find the file in mainframe server which create  last 10 minutes  it shows error like
"FSUM6372 Unknown option "-cmin"
Usage: find directory ... expression"
 it not accept the -mmin , -cmin , -amin this command
but i want to find the file which create last -10 minutes changed file

how to find it and anyone please help me on this case

```
find /input \( -name  [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[A-Z][A-Z].dat \) -cmin -10
FSUM6372 Unknown option "-cmin"
Usage: find directory ... expression
```

Comment: DO you want to search for files changed in last 10 minutes?

Comment: yes but in this server box version is OS/390 WMI1 26.00 04 2964 is not accepting any command like -cmin,-amin,-mmin..etc ..but i want the files which created at last 5 minutes ago

Comment: anybody please help me on this

Comment: Do you have `touch` command? Can you use `date -d`?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  Why do you think cmin or mmin are valid options?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to not know what operating system you're running on, or anything about said operating system, which is concerning.  You're running the command on z/OS V2R3, based on the output of uname.  z/OS is POSIX compliant, and the options you're specifying on the find command aren't supported, as shown in the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa500/find.htm).

I can think of two options:  first, obtain a version of find that does support said options, or, second, use the tools present on the platform.

For the first option, you can obtain findutils, which includes find, from [Rocket Software](https://www.rocketsoftware.com/zos-open-source/tools).  Note that this requires an account with them, and may violate your site's security rules.  It's also possible that this version is already installed; you should talk to your system programmer.

For the second option, find does have the *–newer* option, which looks for files created more recently than the specified file.  You can use this in conjunction with the [touch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxa500/touch.htm) command's *-t* option, which will allow you to set a last modified date and time for a given file.  So instead of *-cmin -10*, you would specify *-t filename*.